# How to determine when the sum is negative, zero, and positive

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Consider the sum $$\sum\limits_{m\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}} \frac{(1+A^{2})\cos(m\theta)\sin^{2}(\frac{m\kappa}{2})}{m^{s}},$$
where $A,s \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and both $\theta, \kappa$ are rational multiplies of $\pi$. I want to know when this sum is negative (resp. positive, zero).

---

In my attempt, I have considered a particular value of $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and noticed that the sequence $\{\cos(m\theta)\}$ alternates: $0,-1,0,1,\cdots$ However I am not sure how to then determine when the numerator of the sum would be negative since the sign is alternating.

The period is $4$ in this case

Comment: Have you tried evaluating it as a Fourier series?

Comment: No, I have not. Could you elaborate why?

Comment: Do you know there is a simple answer to this? The $(1+A^2)$ is irrelevant. If $s<1$, I doubt the sum converges. If $s>1$, the sign is mostly determined by the first couple of terms. If you take the first 1/2/3 terms, you can think up some bounds on $\theta$ pretty easily.

Comment: If you have the time, I would really appreciate your comments with detail about bounds on theta as an Answer. In the meantime, I will attempt finding bounds myself.

Comment: For example: If $2\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$ then the first two terms are positive, so the sign is positive for $s$ not too small. I'd suggest looking at this [plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3feez0xmdr) for what you need

Comment: For $s > 1$, the series of absolute values is majorized by $(1+A^2)\sum\frac 1{m^s}$, which is known to converge, so it must converge as well. Absolutely convergent series are also convergent.

Comment: For $s \le 1$, the periodicity of the numerator allows us to rearrange the sum into an alternating series whose terms converge to $0$. Such series converge. While in general rearrangements of conditionally convergent series need not converge or diverge with the original series, this periodic rearrangment is an exception. It provably does converge to the same limit as the original.

Comment: In the case of $s>1$, we further have that the sum $\sum \frac{1}{m^s} = \zeta(s) $. But this is not the sum we originally start out with. I particularly want to know when $(1+A^{2})\sum \frac{\cos(m\theta)\sin^2(\frac{m \kappa}{2})}{m^s}< 0$